# Can we omit the subject of second sentence when they relate to each other

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, clauses, subjects

I am having the following construction.

> 1: The figure demonstrates that the most frequent rmse falls within the
>   range of 0.3m-0.6m. ***The deviation*** is approximately equal to the
>   resolution of data.

Is it possible to omit the subject of second sentence and join like this.

> 2: The figure demonstrates that the most frequent rmse falls within the
>   range of 0.3m-0.6m ***which is*** approximately equal to the
>   resolution of data.

So, I want to know whether my second sentence is correct or not. thanks

Comment: Is 'the most frequent rmse' the same as 'The deviation'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version is correct if *the most frequent rmse* means the same thing as *the deviation*. However, I would add a comma before *which*.

Comment: I can't agree with this as it stands. If you *add a comma before "which"*, there ***is*** no "second sentence".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am referring to the OP's second sentence highlighted in yellow, I hope this makes sense. Or would "second statement" be less confusing?

Comment: oic. I've edited the question to make it clearer what *first/second* mean here. Then I had to change the word "sentence" to "version" in your text, so I could reverse my downvote, if that's okay by you.

Comment: Ok, no problem :-)